# PHP Данные из массива подключенного файла

Tags: php

Имеется файл settings.php:

```
<?php
$dbconfig = array (
'dbhost' => "localhost",
'dbuser' => "...",
'dbpass' => "...",
'dbtable' => "...",
);

$config = array (
'home_title' => "Тестовая версия v0.1",
);
?>
```

Я пытаюсь вывести в файл index.php данные из массива упомянутого файла, однако этого не происходит. При подключении файла выводит True, однако вместо `$title` выводит пустоту. Не могу понять, почему не работает. Ведь если код из settings.php вставить в index.php, то все работает.

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once ('settings.php');

$title = $config['home_title'];

echo <<<HTML
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>$title</title>
........
HTML;
?>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51300/discussion-on-question-by-faik371-php-----).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно файлы были в разных кодировках. Сделал оба файла в utf-8 with bom и все заработало.